# Best way to store data in to hash for flexible "pivot-table" like calculations

Tags: perl, hash, count

I have a data set with following fields.

host name, model, location, port number, activated?, up?

I would convert them into a hash structure (perhaps similar to below)

```
my %switches = (
    a => {
        "hostname" => "SwitchA",
        "model" => "3750",
        "location" => "Building A"
        "total_ports" => 48,
        "configured_ports" => 30,
        "used_ports" => 24,
    },
    b => {
        "hostname" => "SwitchB",
        "model" => "3560",
        "location" => "Building B"
        "total_ports" => 48,
        "configured_ports" => 36,
        "used_ports" => 20,
    },        
},
);
```

In the end I want to generate statistics such as:
 No. of switches per building,
 No. of switches of each model per building
 Total no. of up ports per building

The statistics may not be just restricted to building wise, may be even switch based (i.e, no. of switches 95% used etc.,). With the given data structure how can I enumerate those counters?

Conversely, is there a better way to store my data? I can think of at least one format:

```
 <while iterating over records>
 {
 hash{$location}->{$model_name}->count++;
 if ($State eq 'Active') {hash{$location}->{up_ports}->count++};
```

What would be the better way to go about this? If I chose the first format (where all information is intact inside the hash) how can I mash the data to produce different statistics? (some example code snippets would be of great help!)

Comment: The question is too general. Assuming that your data layout looks quite ok, I can't see where your problems are. Please name a specific problem you have and what you did to solve it and where you get stuck.

Comment: I agree with your observation. I started out with the hash structure listed above, but I was not able to count ports usage based on each location (basically need to summarize based on key value and not key). It made me wonder whether there was a more elegant way to store & retrieve the data and that is why I approached the experts. 
I did not want to restrict the answers to mere solving the primary challenge (i.e, performing arithmetic on key values grouped by their sibling key values) and that is why I made the question too generic. I'm sorry if the question looks directionless.

Comment: Exactly this "I was not able" is the point. If you want a good answer, or an answer at all, you need to invest something. You have difficulties to express *all*  you want to do in perl. But it is absolutely necessary that you express at least a start in perl, and the rest in english or maybe pseudocode.

Comment: Looks like I have difficulties in English as well, to express all I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want querying flexibility, a "database" strategy is often good. You can do that directly, by putting the data into something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Under that approach, you would be able to issue a wide variety of queries against the data without much coding of your own.

Alternatively, if you're looking for a pure Perl approach, the way to approximate a database table is by using an array-of-arrays or, even better for code readability, an array-of-hashes. The outer array is like the database table. Each hash within that array is like a database record. Your Perl-based queries would end up looking like this:

```
my @query_result = grep {
    $_->{foo} == 1234 and
    $_->{bar} eq 'fubb'
} @data;
```

If you have so many rows that query performance becomes a bottleneck, you can create your own indexes, using a hash.

```
%data_by_switch = (
    'SwitchA' => [0, 4, 13, ...],  # Subscripts to @data.
    'SwitchB' => [1, 12, ...],
    ...
);
```

My answer is based on answers I received for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182469), which has some similarities with your question.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies my apprehensions about the data structure I am using. But I am still stumped on how to count. In SQL parlance I would like to do
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SWITCHES GROUP BY LOCATION`

Comment: @Benny Using the data structure I outlined, you would use use a hash (for example, `%counts_by_location`) to produce the tallies needed:  `$counts_by_location{ $_->{location} } ++ for @data`. If you take the SQLite approach, you would simply query the database directly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Now it looks so straightforward! For instance, if I want to count number of switches models per property I would do `$counts_by_location{ $_->{'location'} }->{$_->{'model'}} ++ for %all_switches;`It didn't look all that straightforward in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you have a list of tuples, for the sake of the discussion it is enough to consider objects with 2 attributes, for example location and ports_used. So, for example:

```
(["locA", 23], ["locB", 42], ["locA", 13])  # just the values as tuples, no keys
```

And you want a result like:

```
("locA" => 36, "locB" => 42)
```

Is this correct? If so, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes, how would you do that? In Perl at least?

Comment: Please tell me first how you would do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured it out now and also posted my little snippet if someone else is looking for a similar answer.